# Pandas : Select series from dataframe loses information of column level names

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2],[3,4]], names=['i', 'j']), index=[0]).fillna(0)


In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
i  1     2
j  3  4  3  4
0  0  0  0  0
```

When we select a `Series` from a `DataFrame`, we get the `index` information completely.

```
In [13]: df.iloc[:, 0]
Out[13]: 
0    0
Name: (1, 3), dtype: int64
```

The `Series.name` contains a particular value from `DataFrame.columns`. In the case of `MultiIndex`, the `Series.name` is a `tuple`. However, I could not find a way to access the name of levels that the `Series.name` correspond to.

In the example above, is there any way to find out the level names `('i', 'j')` from the Series. Is there any attribute in `pd.Series` that contains this information?

#### Why this becomes a problem?

Consider building an API. where a column represents a sequence of biological data from a person. We want to build an API which reads this and returns a number. As part of the API, we want to support an optional level called 'AGE'. If it is present in the dataframe, will be used in addition to the sequence of data. Now you want to build the API such that the function works on the series and when called with DataFrame it simply does df.apply on the individual columns and returns. It will be easier for the user to get one column from the dataframe and still be able to call our function. Now the function has all information but not the names of levels.

Comment: u can tell that the first entry in the tuple belongs to i and the other, j. the shape or tuple stays that way and u can tell. unless there is sth else to this question, which I have not deciphered

Comment: The problem is if we build a generic function that operates on both DataFrames and Series and it looks for values at specific column levels, it becomes difficult.

Comment: it would be helpful if u added a scenario that captures this in ur question

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope I made it clear.